# Выделить из каждой группы лучший результат

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Дана таблица. Необходимо получить как можно более полную информацию об людях в группах. А именно взять для каждой группы (group_id) самого успешного человека (определяется max(mark)). То есть, как я понял, мне нужно сгруппировать людей по группам (GROUP BY group_id). Просто выделить информацию не пойдёт. Т.е. такая процедура

```
select st.group_id, max(mark) as maxMark
from students as st
group by st.group_id
```

конечно же выделит только лучшее значение для каждой группы, НО добавить необходимые столбы в эту процедуру я не могу.

Наколдовав немного, получился этот монстр. Нижеуказанная процедура делает то что нужно - выдаёт все данные о самом успешном человеке для каждой группы. Может быть, более опытные люди подскажут более простой путь решения?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    students AS stOuter
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
    group_id, MAX(mark) AS maxMark
FROM
    students
GROUP BY group_id) AS stInner ON stOuter.group_id = stInner.group_id
    AND stOuter.mark = stInner.maxMark
GROUP BY stOuter.group_id
```

Comment: Да нет, не монстр, вполне адекватный запрос. По крайней мере у меня придумать лучше не получилось.

Comment: @msi выложите это в ответы, я помечу. спасибо

Comment: Выложил. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последняя группировка не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как вы посылаете запросы, если с помощью PHP, то я, как знающий основы SQL и хорошо знающий PHP, сделал бы с помощью циклов запросы на каждую группу, но если у вас эта задача стоит только на SQL, то, прошу прощения, здесь я бессилен, хотя если покопаться в Интернете, можно много узнать. Это, я думаю, вы и сами сможете сделать!

Comment: нет. Я не хочу тратить ресурсы на множество(цикл) запросов если можно сделать один.